# Alternative to "Create site template" for publishing sites?

Tags: publishing-site, site-template

As many of you know for a publishing site "save as template" is not supported by MS. Although there are hack to save the publishing site as template, it is not guaranteed to work properly.

And here is my situation i need to have some site templates(there will be many customization in the template), so that in my portal, content-authors must have "X Portal Sub-Site" choice in the "Create Site" menu?

What is the appropriate way for publishing sites?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom publishing site definition using Visual Studio solutions. Check out this link for instance: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/08/creating-deploying-and-updating-custom.html.

Comment: Hello, is the article on the link for 2007 ? And also applies to 2010 ?

Comment: Yes, you can also create publishing site definitions for 2010 in a similar way. Please use Google to find some tutorials.